# SFML C++ stop console from logging: "Failed to set DirectInput device axis mode: 1"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sfml

I have this problem going for a while, that when i compile a basic SFML window check the console keeps spamming the following error message

`Failed to set DirectInput device axis mode: 1`

Is there anyway to keep this message from spamming my console log? 
I'm on windows using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Okay actually found the solution.
To ignore the error message you just use:

```
sf::err().rdbuf(NULL);
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.